# How to use dispatch from redux in this station?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

```
class DetailPage extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        dispatch =  dispatch.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        dispatch(action(data))
   }
    render(){
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        return(
                <div>
                    {this.props.params.id}
                </div>
            )
    }
}
```

I want to dispatch action, when component updates the params from the router.

How to make dispatch is a function?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as text, rather than attempting to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to this way

```
this.props.dispatch(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to pass down a function in props that includes the dispatch wrapped around the action creator. This is a common pattern when using redux with react and is shown in both the [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) examples and redux [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

The example given in the documentation is;

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onTodoClick: (id) => {
           dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
        }
    }
}
```